# How can I access an struct attribute from an array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct

What I want to do is to, after storing several objects of type CodigosAutorizacion inside an array:

```
for value in 0..<(array.count) {
  let codeArray = CodigosAutorizacion(
      code: validateData!["codigo"] as? String,
      codeCancel: validateData!["cancela_codigo"] as? String,
      codeSite: validateData!["cod_sitio"] as? String,
      codeSiteCancel: validateData!["cancela_cod_sitio"] as? String,
      instance: validateData!["instancia"] as? String
    )
  codes.append(codeArray)

}
```

Access the object attributes from the array like this:

```
 codeCell.codigoSitio.text = codes[indexPath.row].instance
```

This piece throws me the next errors

-No exact matches in call to subscript

-Reference to member 'instancia' cannot be resolved without a contextual type

this is because ´codes´ is an array and not a CodigosAutorizacion type

Storing these objects in an array is important because I will need to generate a table with several of this CodigosAutorizacion objects. Is there any way this can be possible?

Comment: Oï there. you can't call an object outside it's scope. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science). To put it in a nutshell, whenever you create a scope with " { } " whatever is instanciated inside it cannot be accessed outside

Comment: in other words, put `codes.append(codeArray)` inside your for loop

Comment: I think you have probably just put the } in the wrong place in your question, since otherwise you would get an error referencing `codeArray`. How is `codes` declared?  Also, you are iterating based  on the size of something called `array` but referencing values from a dictionary called `validateData`. This dictionary will be the same for each iteration of your loop

Comment: @Olympiloutre, @workingdog Yes sorry, my mistake. the `codes.append(codesArray)` is actually inside the for loop

Comment: @Paulw11 `codes` is declared as `codes: Array<Any>`. Yes I am iterating `array` because `array` is an Array holding json type objects, so `validateData` is a dictionary that holds `array` values for the for loop to assign them to `CodigosAutorizacion` struct values

Comment: The thing here is that when I do `let codeArray = CodigosAutorizacion`, `codeArray` is `CodigosAutorizacion` type, so when I add that to codes array, I am adding `CodigosAutorizacion` type objects right?, I need them to be `CodigosAutorizacion` type in order to access their attributes (code, codeCancel, codeSite, instance, etc) when filling the table cells: `codeCell.codigoSitio.text = codes[indexPath.row].instance` but because I am referencing `codes` which is holding all those `CodigosAutorizacion` in here which is an array type I cant do it

Comment: Your life will be much simpler if you adopt `Decodable` instead of decoding your objects manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
var codes = [CodigosAutorizacion]()

for value in 0..<(array.count) {
  let codeArray = CodigosAutorizacion(
    code: validateData!["codigo"] as? String,
          codeCancel: validateData!["cancela_codigo"] as? String,
          codeSite: validateData!["cod_sitio"] as? String,
          codeSiteCancel: validateData!["cancela_cod_sitio"] as? String,
          instance: validateData!["instancia"] as? String
    )
    codes.append(codeArray)
}
```

-- Try this --

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! it was a problem with the `codes` array declaration, it was not supposed to be `var codes: Array<Any>` but instead `var codes: Array<CodigosAutorizacion>` in order to access CodigosAutorizacion's properties

Comment: Did the other answer help you? If yes, please mark it as the answer instead of adding your own.